# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\frac{(x(\pi + 49))^{\frac{15}{7}}}{\pi ^ {2} (x^{\pi}+7)} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I was looking at a [website](http://durofy.com/5-most-beautiful-questions-from-integral-calculus/) that contained 5 integrals that supposedly have beautiful solutions; I managed to solve #4 yet I can't figure out how to solve #1:

$$\int\frac{(x(\pi + 49))^{\frac{15}{7}}}{\pi ^ {2} (x^{\pi}+7)} dx $$

I've tried doing a u substitution with $x^\pi$ and $\pi^2 x^\pi$ with no success. Any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First of all I suggest you to put the constants out of the integral.

Comment: I think the primitive function in this case will be non-elementary. It will be possible to express it in terms of a hypergeometric function.

Comment: You should probably use integration by parts $u=\pi^2x^{\pi}$ And $dv=x^{15/7}dx$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility suggested by the exponent of $\pi$ below and the exponent with denominator $7$ above is that you are expected to use the false equation $\pi=\frac{22}{7}$, where $\frac{22}{7}$ is a "famous" approximation for $\pi$. Note that $\pi-1\approx\frac{15}{7}$. With that, you have:

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{(x(\pi + 49))^{\frac{15}{7}}}{\pi ^ {2} (x^{\pi}+7)}\,dx
&\approx \int\frac{(x(\pi + 49))^{\pi-1}}{\pi ^ {2} (x^{\pi}+7)}\,dx\\
&=\frac{(\pi + 49)^{\pi-1}}{\pi ^ {2}}\int\frac{x^{\pi-1}}{x^{\pi}+7}\,dx\\
&=\frac{(\pi + 49)^{\pi-1}}{\pi ^ {2}}\frac{1}{\pi}\ln\mathopen{}\left(x^\pi+7\right)\mathclose{}+C\\
&=\frac{(\pi + 49)^{\pi-1}}{\pi ^ {3}}\ln\mathopen{}\left(x^\pi+7\right)\mathclose{}+C\\
\end{align}$$

Of course this is not really an antiderivative.

Comment: But it's a good observation. (+1)

Comment: Very nice approximation !

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring, for the time being, the constant terms, we face an integral which looks like
$$A=\int \frac {x^a}{x^b+c}\,dx$$ Changing variable $x^b= c t$ we end with
$$A=\frac{c^{\frac{a-b+1}b}}{b }\int \frac {t^{\frac{a-b+1}b} }{t+1}\,dt=k  \int \frac {t^{\alpha}}{t+1}\,dt$$ and, except for a few values of $\alpha$, the last integral does not show a closed form but expresses in terms of hypergeometric function as mickep commented.
$$\int \frac {t^{\alpha}}{t+1}\,dt=\frac{t^{\alpha +1}}{\alpha +1} \,  \, _2F_1(1,\alpha +1;\alpha +2;-t)$$
Using this result, for the integral of concern, after simplifications,
$$I=\int\frac{(x(\pi + 49))^{\frac{15}{7}}}{\pi ^ {2} (x^{\pi}+7)}\, dx=\frac{(49+\pi )^{15/7}}{22 \pi ^2}\,\, x^{22/7} \,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{22}{7 \pi };1+\frac{22}{7 \pi
   };-\frac{x^{\pi }}{7}\right)$$
Comparing to $$J=\frac{(\pi + 49)^{\pi-1}}{\pi ^ {3}}\,\,\log\mathopen{}\left(x^\pi+7\right)+C_1$$ as nicely proposed by alex.jordan in his answer, or to $$K= \frac{7 (49+\pi )^{15/7} }{22 \pi ^2}\log \left(x^{22/7}+7\right)+C_2$$  what is obtained for the integrals between $0$ and $t$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 t & I & J & K\\
 1 & 20.5889 & 20.4948 & 20.5892 \\
 2 & 125.869 & 125.193 & 125.845 \\
 3 & 263.344 & 261.826 & 263.208 \\
 4 & 385.308 & 382.990 & 385.003 \\
 5 & 487.088 & 484.071 & 486.602 \\
 6 & 572.727 & 569.099 & 572.062 \\
 7 & 646.142 & 641.976 & 645.307 \\
 8 & 710.205 & 705.557 & 709.210 \\
 9 & 766.954 & 761.871 & 765.807 \\
 10 & 817.852 & 812.371 & 816.561 \\
 11 & 863.975 & 858.128 & 862.548 \\
 12 & 906.133 & 899.946 & 904.576 \\
 13 & 944.947 & 938.444 & 943.267 \\
 14 & 980.907 & 974.107 & 979.109 \\
 15 & 1014.40 & 1007.32 & 1012.49 \\
 16 & 1045.74 & 1038.40 & 1043.73 \\
 17 & 1075.20 & 1067.60 & 1073.07 \\
 18 & 1102.97 & 1095.14 & 1100.75 \\
 19 & 1129.25 & 1121.19 & 1126.93 \\
 20 & 1154.18 & 1145.91 & 1151.77
\end{array}
\right)$$ which confirms (even if not needed, how good is his approximation.